# How to redirect from folder having permission `Deny from all`, error `You don't have permission to access / on this server`

Tags: .htaccess

I have .htaccess in `/domainName` folder with rule `Deny from all` and some other rules.
After this if i type :

http://www.domainName.com - i am redirected correctly

http://www.domainName.com/uri - i am redirected correctly

domainName.com - i am getting the error `You don't have permission to access / on this server. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Structure:

```
/domainName/
/domainName/.htaccess
/domainName/public
/domainName/public/.htaccess
```

/domainName/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews

Redirect https://domainName.com https://www.domainName.com/public/index\.php
Redirect https://www.domainName.com https://www.domainName.com/public/index\.php
Redirect http://domainName.com https://www.domainName.com/public/index\.php
Redirect http://www.domainName.com https://www.domainName.com/public/index\.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 


#1# the error You don't have permission to access / on this server. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
# Deny from all

#2#does not give errors, but i am not able to access https://www.domainName.com/public/index.php,  dditionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
#<FilesMatch  ".">
#    Deny from all
#</FilesMatch>

#3# gives errors, about wrong configuration
# <DirectoryMatch ".">
#  Deny from all
# </DirectoryMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems, that one has to redirect in case of deny:

```
Deny from all
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.somedomain.com/public/index.php/
```

If redirect in case of deny, there will not be the error for url  somedomain.com, or www. somedomain.com

Structure:

```
/domainName/
/domainName/.htaccess
/domainName/public
/domainName/public/.htaccess
```

When in somedomain.com/public/ there shall be another .htaccess, whith rule `Allow from all`.

Full .htacess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex /public/index.php


#redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 
#[L,R=301]

# Now, rewrite any request to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=301]


Deny from all

ErrorDocument 403 https://www.somedomain.com/public/index.php/
```

In somedomain.com/public/ there shall be another .htaccess, whith rule `Allow from all`.

the error You don't have permission to access / on this server. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.